# Custom Edit Field Creation problem

Tags: blackberry, uitextfield

I have created one screen in which there is background.and on that i am creating a Custom Edit Fields with one button.now my problem is that my edit field is displaying on upper side.i want to make to the center of the screen.what modifications i have to do so.i am giving my code snippet.

```
 public class CancelBooking extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
 public LabelField heading; 
ButtonField next; 
String emp_id,emp_name,salary; 
public CancelBooking(String id,String name,String sal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    emp_id=id; 
    emp_name=name; 
    salary=sal; 
    }
  //    protected void sublayout(int width, int height){
  //            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), height);
  //            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), this.getPreferredHeight());
  //            int leftPadding = Display.getWidth()/2 -this.getPreferredWidth()/2;
  //            int rightPadding = Display.getWidth() - leftPadding -this.getPreferredWidth();
  //            
  //            setPadding(5,rightPadding,5,leftPadding);
   //           invalidate();
   //       }
    CancelBooking() 
    { 
        heading = new LabelField(){
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        heading.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, Font.getDefault().getHeight()+2));
        heading.setText("Check-In");

        getMainManager().setBackground(
                BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(
                  Bitmap.getBitmapResource("PlainScreen.png")));
    //setTitle("First Screen"); 

    BasicEditField id=new BasicEditField("Last Name: ",""); 
    BasicEditField name=new BasicEditField("Confirmation Number: ",""); 
    //BasicEditField sal=new BasicEditField("Salary: ",""); 
    add(id); 
    add(name); 
    //add(sal); 
    next=new ButtonField("Next"); 
    next.setChangeListener(this); 
  //        add(next); 
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
    { 

    if(field==next) 
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MenuScreen());  
    } 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add FIELD_HCENTER and FIELD_VCENTER in the style of your field.
Consider reading this link
["Managers of Blackberry docs"](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Manager_1579416_11.jsp)